# Limit Firefox extension on specific browser versions

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am building a firefox extension and I want it to run on a specific browser version.

For example, if the user has Firefox 50 and in the settings (manifest.json I believe), I have set to run only on 48 or lower, then don't enable the extension.
And if someone comes and downloads the extension and has a version 46, then the extension would run.

Is there a possibility to make that kind of restriction?

Comment: To clarify, you want to set version 48 as _max_ version?

Comment: @Xan Yes, I made that as an example, but you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`browser_specific_settings` key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/browser_specific_settings) in the WebExtension manifest:

> `strict_max_version`: maximum version of Gecko to support. If the Firefox version on which the extension is being installed or run is above this version, then the extension will be disabled, or not permitted to be installed. Defaults to `"*"`, which disables checking for a maximum version.

```
"browser_specific_settings": {
  "gecko": {
    "id": "addon@example.com",
    "strict_max_version": "48.0"
  }
}
```

You can set both min and max version this way.

Comment: Please note that the "strict_max_version" is often ignored on AMO in manifest.json and it is best to manually set the max version on add-on's edit page.